# How to write a method to ask what index and what value to update users information in Array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpdateUserInfo { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Name", "LastName", "08/19/1995",
                "123 main Street, mcLean, VA 22102", "7576330954"));

       // To update user's information, please edit value in double quotes, this is a basic way, but can we create our own method for it
//        userList.set(0, "Name"); // name
//        userList.set(1, "LastName");
//        userList.set(2, "08/19/1995");
//        userList.set(3, "123 main Street, mcLean, VA 22102");
//        userList.set(4, "7576330954");

        System.out.print(userList);
       // changeUserInfo();

    }
```

// Here is my attempt to create my own method

```
    public static void changeUserInfo(String[] name, String lName, String dob, String address, String phone){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you wish to update your info? ");
        boolean flag = scan.hasNextBoolean();
        if(flag == true){
            System.out.println("What info do you want to update? Name? LastName?");
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking to add boolean to see if they user want to change info, if yes  then change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpdateUserInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrayList = { "Name", "LastName", "08/19/1995",
                "123 main Street, mcLean, VA 22102", "7576330954"};
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("to edit the name type: 0, \nto edit the last name type: 1\nto edit birthday type:2\n" +
                "to edit address type:3\nand to edit id type:4");
        int option = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("change the value: ");
        String desire = scan.next();// this is where you input the replacement value
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(" before:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayList));
        System.out.println(" after:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(changeUserInfo(arrayList,option,desire)));
    }

    public static String[] changeUserInfo(String[] array,int value, String to){
        array[value] = to;// the [value] is to access the list in the desired area you want to make  a change.
        return array;
    }
}
```

Here I created a menu to make the user choose the number according to the value he wants to change. After that I created a method that returns an array and accessed the the array using the "value" as index, and made the change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you please comment on this line? array[value] = to;   i understand we expect an Array of String as a return type in our method, but what is [value] represent?  Why there is no this kind of code to actually set/edit arraylist userList.set(0, "Name");

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to create an input form for a list of people. You might want to introduce a `User` class which will have all the fields for the user.

Regarding the update User flow, the part inside the flag boolean check should use some sort of identifier and value mechanism. The identifier selected in one entry will have the value passed as the next input.

As the first statement, you should ask the id or email or any other unique identifier for the user, the info has to be updated.

Next, show the list of fields and a corresponding number which will be entered by the user. People prefer to use a reference instead of typing long words, the trouble of spelling errors is cumbersome. Enums are a great way to manage field name with a corresponding number.

Once the user entered a number (identifier), show the prompt of which field will be updated and show a sample value in brackets. The user can then enter the new value and you can update the information.

You can either prompt next to update a different field for the same user without asking for the id or start the update flow all over again. Cheers!